# Why does NetworkManager explicitly support tun/tap devices?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, networkmanager

Apparently NetworkManager [recently gained support for *macvlan* interfaces](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=e25d144d770df2d18c5f37ee72b971b7a40ea2fd&utm_source=anzwix).  I notice it also supports *macvtap*, and the patch shows it already had some support for *tun*/*tap* devices.

I thought tap interfaces are normally created by VM software.  Then the interface can be joined to a bridge.  Or either of tun/tap can have an IP address assigned, again often done by VM software like virt-manager/libvirt.  For macvtap, there isn't even anything that NetworkManager could configure!

Alternatively, tun/tap devices are used for userspace network tunnels such as OpenVPN.  But I don't understand why you would configure a raw tun/tap device using NetworkManager.  You still need to run something like OpenVPN to drive data through the tun/tap device.

I just can't make sense of it.

Question: Can anyone think of a reason to create tun/tap/macvtap devices using NetworkManager?

---

## Glossary

*macvlan* is an alternative to bridging for networking Virtual Machines.  Apparently it avoids some overhead.  I haven't worked out the corresponding limitations.

[*tun*/*tap*](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun/faq.html) network interfaces provide a corresponding character device, which allows virtual machine implementations to read/write network packets from the interface.  *tap* works at layer 2 (ethernet); *tun* only works at layer 3 (IP).

*macvtap* provides the same character device, but packets either come out a physical device the *macvtap* was bound to, or are bridged to a different macvtap/macvlan device on the same physical interface.

It is sometimes useful to create a macvlan interface for the host as well.

Comment: I don't care about NetworkManager, but I don't like your contention that tun/tap is "normally" only used for vm networking or, worse for the straight-jacketing libvirt kind of it. You can do anything you want with a tun/tap device, including implementing any tunneling protocol you want. But even then, using a vm as a virtual router has uses -- I've used such a setup in the past out of expediency, because configuring non-trivial ipv6 networking is such a PITA on a standard linux distro, and easy on OpenWRT.

Comment: @mosvy I've added OpenVPN as a second example, hope you find this more likable.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to allow otherwise unprivileged software such as a VM or tunnel manager to use a preconfigured tun/tap device so as to avoid the need of a setuid security hole or a special binary with specific capabilities which can be (mis-)used to raise privileges.

Comment: So this included a configuration for NM to enable IP forwarding?  Otherwise the VM would only get to talk to the host.  Tunnelling sounds plausible though.