# Allowing a non-root user to create TUN/TAP interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-interface, capabilities

I have a situation where I need a non-root user to be allowed to create TUN/TAP interfaces. I understand that this requires the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability.

There have been [other questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255867/why-does-networkmanager-explicitly-support-tun-tap-devices) about this, but the answers seem to focus on granting the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability to a **file**/**program**, not to the user. In my case, I need the capability to be assigned to the **user**, so they can use whatever tool they see fit to create the interfaces (i.e. not restricted to a specific file/program used to create them).

Is this possible in Linux? Specifically, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

For context, the reason for this is that I'm creating the TUN interface through a custom program that makes the system calls, and I need this to work while debugging it. Since it builds a new binary every time I run the debugger, switching to root and assigning the capability to the binary and then switching back to debug the binary is not feasible.

Comment: As a general rule, the kernel does not keep a list of users at all, so you cannot pin any properties to a user. The check whether you can do something by a user is always done by looking at the something, and looking at whether that has set particular privileges for the UID of the user trying to do it.

Comment: In short. To create: no. To use: yes (because such device has a uid/gid user setting).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ambient capability set via some file capabilities on a wrapper (`wrapper.c`):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHELL "/bin/bash"

char *const args[] = { SHELL, NULL };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cap_iab_t iab = cap_iab_get_proc();
  if (cap_iab_set_vector(iab, CAP_IAB_AMB, CAP_SYS_ADMIN, CAP_SET)) {
    perror("not able to raise bit");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (cap_iab_set_proc(iab)) {
    perror("unable to set iab bit");
    exit(1);
  }
  execv(SHELL, args);
  perror("execv failed");
  exit(1);
}
```

If `$USERWANTED` is the username of the user you want to be able to do this:

```bash
$ gcc -o wrapper wrapper.c -lcap
$ sudo chown $USERWANTED wrapper
$ sudo chmod go-wx wrapper
$ sudo setcap "cap_sys_admin,cap_setpcap=pe" wrapper
```

Only `$USERWANTED` can execute this binary, because of the `chmod` line. When they do, the `wrapper` program adds the Ambient capability and runs a shell. It and its children have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability:

```
$ sudo -u $USERWANTED
$ exec ./wrapper
$ capsh --print|grep Current
Current: cap_sys_admin=eip
Current IAB: ^cap_sys_admin
```

You may still find it difficult to debug your program. This is because programs that run with capabilities can only be debugged by programs that also have those capabilities.